# How to send URL parameters from GWT client to Server side for validation

Tags: java, gwt, client, servlet-filters, gwt-rpc

I am working on enhancing an existing GWT project, I am adding authentication using PING.

So here is what the flow is:

1. User enters application URL http://...../library-ui
2. I want to use servlet filter to filter all the URL's and check for code parameter in the URL, if I don't see code parameter in the URL, I want to redirect them to PING authentication URL.
3. Once PING authenticates it re-directs to http://...../library-ui/?code=xxxxxx
4. This "code" is required to get the JwT token with respect to the user

I am adding a filter below:

```
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    System.out.println(httpRequest);
    String requestURI = httpRequest.getParameter("code");

    System.out.println(requestURI);
    if (!requestURI.contains("code")) {
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        httpResponse.sendRedirect("https://pingwebsite/as/authorization.oauth2?client_id=XXX&response_type=code");
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

But the issue is that my request URI does not have code parameter.

`System.out.println(requestURI);` prints - library-ui.

Once I get the code from the URL I will be able to proceed further.

Comment: This ain't gonna be secure. How about you use an OpenID Connect library instead of rolling your own without full understanding? `redirect_uri`s are supposed to set cookies and redirect.

Comment: in the URL I only get Auth code, this does not have any info about the user or the token. Once I get this I will do backend server calls to get the actual Token. Let me know if it will be still vulnerable, I am new to GwT world, any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I recommend you carefully review https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6819

Comment: 3 issues: 
1) `String requestURI = httpRequest.getParameter("code");` this is not the `requestUri`, it is the code parameter, which is actually what you need. 
2) `if (!requestURI.contains("code")) {` this is not the correct control. you already have the code. you should check for not null and not empty string
3) after this `httpResponse.sendRedirect(.....` you do not have a return statement, so the filter will keep processing the request as if it passed the control.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue, I had to use window.location to get the details from browser and perform an RPC call to server side. I then had to request PING for Jwt token with authorization code and validate it.